# How do we calculate Standard Errors for effect-coded variables?

Tags: categorical-data, interaction, standard-error, contrasts

I'm a beginner following [this UCLA tutorial](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faq-how-do-i-interpret-the-coefficients-of-an-effect-coded-variable-involved-in-an-interaction-in-a-regression-model/) to figure out how to interpret coefficients for effect-coded categorical predictors and have a couple of questions regarding their regression table below, which is for a model that looks at the effect of a predictor called Study Methods (where you have Recitation and Writing as levels) on an outcome variable called Words. The predictor is effect-coded into a regressor M1 with Recitation as the reference level such that:

[image]

The regression table:

| Words | Coef. | Std. Err. | t | P>|t| | [95% Conf. Interval] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| M1 | -2 | 1.074968 | -1.86 | 0.112 | -4.630351 |
| _cons | 10 | 1.074968 | 9.30 | 0.000 | 7.369649 |

1. If unlike in the tutorial, my dependent variable was categorical, how would I go about calculating the grand mean manually?
2. In the tutorial, they interpret the regression coefficients b0 and b1 by averaging across groups. So for the two conditions, I can have the predicted score/means by plugging in regressor values such that

   Words(recitation) = b0 + b1 = 10 + (-2) = 8
   and, Words(writing) = b0 - b1 = 10 - (-2) = 12

I understand how they're interpreting these coefficients. My question is: Would we calculate the Standard Errors for these predictors by averaging across groups in the same way? I'm trying to ultimately calculate z-values for the predictors.

3. The same tutorial [here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faq-how-do-i-interpret-the-coefficients-of-an-effect-coded-variable-involved-in-an-interaction-in-a-regression-model/#interaction-of-2-effect-coded-categorical-predictors) talks about interpreting the interaction of two categorical predictors. How would this change if I had these two interacting predictors in my model plus another effect-coded variable? So for instance, in their example, they have 2 effect-coded regressors for the Method variable M1 and M2, and 1 effect-coded regressor for the Deprived Variable D1, such that:

| Method | M1 | M2 | Deprived | D1 | M1D1 | M2D1 | Words |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| recitation | 1 | 0 | No | -1 | -1 | 0 | 9 |
| recitation | 1 | 0 | No | -1 | -1 | 0 | 12 |
| recitation | 1 | 0 | Yes | 1 | 1 | 0 | 6 |

What if I had yet another effect-coded binary categorical regressor for a variable C1 along with the above interacting regressors such that

[image]

Would the intercept in my model regression table still reflect the unweighted grand mean across seven groups?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Welcome to CV, Nayana! I think this is a good first question. However, you could edit it to make it better by giving some more detail. For example, when you write "I understand how they're interpreting the coefficients by averaging across groups and so on." you could be a bit more precise and detailed about the math you do understand, which will help your readers understand what you mean by "the same way." Cheerio!

Comment: Hi, thank you for the recommendations. I've edited it acccordingly.